# How to launch a Rust application from Visual Studio Code?

Tags: rust, visual-studio-code, rust-cargo, rust-language-server

I have installed the Visual Studio Code extensions for Rust:

[image]

I want to run my project and I don't understand where to click.

[image]

I tried clicking **Run Task**, **Run build task**, **Configure Default build task**, but nothing reasonable happens.

Comment: You have installed too many extensions. You should only need one. Pick either [Rust](https://github.com/editor-rs/vscode-rust) or [Rust (rls)](https://github.com/editor-rs/vscode-rust), in this case whichever provides a Build command.

Comment: Which one provides reasonable rust support with build command?

Comment: @StepanYakovenko -> Which one? I always go with the official tools ... which in this case I believe is the second one in your little screenshot - i.e. "Rust (rls)" .

Answer (score 168):

#### Using the [integrated terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal)

Run the following command in the integrated terminal:

```
cargo run
```

---

**TLDR**:
Install [rust-analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust-analyzer) and [Native debugger based on LLDB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb) **extensions**,  then use the **Run** menu (then see the terminal for the result/output):

[image]

You may install these extensions using the terminal commands (and then **restart** the vscode):

```bash
# apt install musl lldb libssl-dev
code --install-extension vadimcn.vscode-lldb
code --install-extension rust-lang.rust-analyzer
code --install-extension tamasfe.even-better-toml
```

---

#### Using [Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)

Shortcut to run the Task: `Ctrl + Shift + B`
Add `cargo run` as a default Task: add `.vscode/tasks.json` file to your project as follows, to use `cargo run` to run the project, change the contents of `.vscode/tasks.json` as follows:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "cargo run",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "~/.cargo/bin/cargo", // note: full path to the cargo
            "args": [
                "run",
                // "--release",
                // "--",
                // "arg1"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now press `Ctrl + Shift + B` to run the Task, or Press `Ctrl + Shift + P` and select `Tasks: Run Build Task` from the Command Palette.

You may add arguments like the comment above e.g.: `"args": ["run", "--release", "--", "arg1"],` (if your app requires it).

(You may open the Command Palette with `Ctrl + Shift + P` and type in `Configure Default Build Task` and press `Enter` to select it. Then select `Rust: cargo build` or `Others`. This generates a `tasks.json` file in your workspace `.vscode` folder).

---

#### Using the [Native debugger based on LLDB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb)

To Run the project:
Press **Ctrl+F5** or select `Run Without Debugging` from the `Run` menu, and see the **terminal** window, for the result:

[image: Native debugger based on LLDB]

For the first time (only once), install the Native debugger based on LLDB, or install using the command line:

```bash
code --install-extension vadimcn.vscode-lldb
```

Then inside your Visual Studio Code project: Press shortcut **Ctrl+F5** then for the first time select `LLDB` then `OK` and `Yes`, **or** create `.vscode/launch.json` file like the following sample, inside your project folder (Also you may select `create a launch.json file` from Debug/Run panel too):

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug executable 'example'",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "build",
                    "--bin=example",
                    "--package=example"
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "name": "example",
                    "kind": "bin"
                }
            },
            "args": [
                // "user_arg1",
                // "user_arg2"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug unit tests in executable 'example'",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "test",
                    "--no-run",
                    "--bin=example",
                    "--package=example"
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "name": "example",
                    "kind": "bin"
                }
            },
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Notes:
I named the project `example` above.
You may uncomment above `// "user_arg1",` if you need args.

---

#### Using the [rust-analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust-analyzer) extension

[Installation](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#installation):

```bash
rustup component add rust-src
code --install-extension rust-lang.rust-analyzer
# code --install-extension matklad.rust-analyzer
```

To **run** the code click on the gray `Run` text above `fn main()`:
[image: the gray Run text above main, image]

---

#### Using the [code-runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension

Install the extension, then open the source file then you will have a play button in the top right corner to **click**, or use default shortcut: `Ctrl+Alt+N` (You may change the shortcut from: `File>Preferences>Keyboard Shortcuts` and enter `code-runner.run` in the search box).
Note: To run the command inside terminal You may set `code-runner.runInTerminal` to `true` from `File>Preferences>Settings` (or press `Ctrl+,`), then enter `code-runner.runInTerminal` in the search box.
**Edit**: This runs only open file e.g.: `rustc main.rs`. You may edit the `code-runner.executorMap` to change the command from:

```
"rust": "cd $dir && rustc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
```

to:

```
"rust": "cargo run",
```

So the Code Runner runs the `cargo run` command each time you click the Play button (or pressing keyboard shortcut):
From menu: `File>Preferences>Settings` (or press `Ctrl+,`) then inside search box, enter:
`code-runner.executorMap` then click `Edit in Settings.json` then edit `"code-runner.executorMap": and change "rust":"cd $dir && rustc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"` to `"rust": "cargo run"`.

Or simply add 3 following lines to VSCode settings JSON (`settings.json` file):

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
  "rust": "cargo run # $fileName"
}
```

---

#### Using the Code Runner custom command

You may set the custom command to run: `"code-runner.customCommand": "cargo run"`
Menu: `File>Preferences>Settings` (or press `Ctrl+,`) then inside search box, enter `customCommand` and set the custom command to run: `cargo run`.
You may change Shortcut to this command for ease of use: From Menu select: `File>Preferences>Keyboard Shortcuts`, then inside search box enter: `customCommand`, then add/change keybinding e.g. press: `Ctrl+L Ctrl+R`

---

#### Using the [`rust-lang.rust`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust) extension

You may install this extension from the command line using:

```bash
code --install-extension rust-lang.rust
```

The plugin uses tasks: You may press `Ctrl + Shift + B` then select options presented, for now, there are only two options:

```
cargo check
cargo build
```

So you need to use the `cargo run` Task presented above (`tasks.json` file).

---

kalitaalexey's 'Rust' extension [was previously another option](https://web.archive.org/web/20200414115913/https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kalitaalexey.vscode-rust) but was removed from the Visual Studio Code Marketplace by 2021, and was [last updated in 2017](https://github.com/editor-rs/vscode-rust/).

Comment: Code Runner doesn't seem to be a right tool, because it ignores my project dependencies and runs only one file (and fails).

Comment: Thank you, yet I don't understand what you mean by 'Never scan the build output' setting, I don't see it.

Comment: Your `Using the rust-lang.rust extension` instructions no longer work unfortunately. You have to use `type: shell` instead of `type: cargo` as described by Kip.

Comment: I need something with a shortcut for "kill current process and run `cargo run` again" Does that exist?

Comment: possible to point cargo.toml file location to run sub project as main cargo file. 

I mean nested cargo.toml inside sub folder since i am studying rust and jump around multiple small sample project.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately there isn't a good solution at the moment. Basically you have to add a task to `tasks.json`, which begins like this:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cargo",
      "subcommand": "check",
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$rustc"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "cargo",
      "subcommand": "build",
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$rustc"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

A.R. suggested adding another identical entry but with `"subcommand": "run"` but it doesn't work. You get this error:

```
Error: The cargo task detection didn't contribute a task for the following configuration:
{
    "type": "cargo",
    "subcommand": "run",
    "problemMatcher": [
        "$rustc"
    ]
}
The task will be ignored.
```

Instead you can add a `"type": "shell"` task. However this still isn't perfect because for some reason adding that task means `cargo check` and `cargo build` don't show up when you press Ctrl-Shift-B at all.

My solution is just to change those to shell tasks too, so your entire `tasks.json` is:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "cargo check",
      "command": "cargo",
      "args": [
          "check"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": [
          "$rustc"
      ],
      "group": "build"
    },
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "cargo build",
      "command": "cargo",
      "args": [
          "build"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": [
          "$rustc"
      ],
      "group": "build"
    },
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "cargo run",
      "command": "cargo",
      "args": [
          "run"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": [
          "$rustc"
      ],
      "group": "build"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My fast way to create a new proyect:

1. init or clone new repo
2. On vsCode install extensions (for me  "Rust and Friends")
3. Create crate(s) if not exists:

   ```
   cargo new myNewApp
   cargo run
   ```
4. Select main.rs (or other xxx.rs source code rust file)
5. Press F5

[image: oohh noo! but no problem]

6. OK

[image: next]

7. YES

Ready! this create **launch.json** file based on yours crates.

[image]

Select your launch configuration and press F5
[image: playing]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working using the VSC extension, [Rust (rls)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust&ssr=false#review-details), using a modified version of AR's post:

```js
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "cargo run",
        "command": "wsl",
        "args": [
            "--",
            "~/.cargo/bin/cargo",
             "run"
        ],
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$rustc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a Rust application in Visual Studio Code with command line arguments, you can configure your task in this way:

```
{
   "label":"Run With Arguments",
   "type":"process",
   "command":"cargo",
   "group":"none",
   "args":[
      "run",
      {
         "value":"--",
         "quoting":"weak"
      },
      {
         "value":"--argumentOne=\"Something\"",
         "quoting":"weak"
      },
      {
         "value":"--argumentTwo=\"Something\"",
         "quoting":"weak"
      }
   ]
}
```

With the addition of `"--"` and weak quoting, you can pass arguments to your application.